# CSS - Inheriting layered background images

Tags: image, background, css

CSS3 supports multiple background images, for example:

```
foo { background-image: url(/i/image1.jpg), url(/i/image2.jpg); }
```

I'd like to be able to add a secondary image to an element with a class though.

So for example, say you have a nav menu.  And each item has a background image.  When a nav item is selected you want to layer on another background image.

I do not see a way to 'add' a background image instead of redeclaring the whole background property.  This is a pain because in order to do this with multi-backgrounds, you would have to write the base bg image over and over for each item if the items have unique images.

Ideally I'd be able to do something like this:

```
li { background: url(baseImage.jpg); }
li.selected { background: url(selectedIndicator.jpg); }
```

And have li.selected's end result appear the same if I did:

```
li.selected { background: url(baseImage.jpg), url(selectedIndicator.jpg); }
```

Update: I also tried the following with no luck (I believe backgrounds are not inherited..)

```
li { background: url(baseImage.jpg), none; }
li.selected { background: inherit, url(selectedIndicator.jpg); }
```

Answer (score 5):

That is, in any case, not the way CSS inheritance works. `inherit` implies that an element should take on the attributes of it's parent element, not previous declarations affecting the same element.

What you want has been proposed as a way to make CSS more object-oriented, but the closest you will get is with a pre-processor like SASS.

For now you actually just have to re-state the first image along with the second.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible, I think you'd have to redefine the whole rule every time.

For example, you could just add a "wrapper" around every item that has the initial background, with the actual item having a transparent background. Then add the background on the item itself when it's selected.

Answer (score 0):

Additive CSS rules still aren't possible as far as I know.

You could try applying the second image to the `::after` pseudo element:

```
li { background: url(baseImage.jpg); position: relative; }
li.selected::after { 
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(selectedIndicator.jpg); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need as you recently.
I finally thought about it and solved using css variables.

```
::root { --selectdropdown: url( '../elements/expand-dark.svg' ); }

select.gender.female { background-image: var(--selectdropdown), url( '../elements/female-dark.svg' ); }
```

When you resetting the attribute, just specify the variable again in the list!