# css layering background image and gradient in two steps

Tags: css

Is this possible, two-stepped background-image selectors:

```
.greenGradient{
   /* background gradient def*/
 }
.iconToo{
   /* layer a given image upon the existing gradient something like:*/
   background-image:url(png.png), existing; 
 }
```

I was looking into `initial` but that doesn't seem to be what I want.

Comment: what do you mean by 2 steps?

Comment: http://askthecssguy.com/articles/css-gradients-and-background-images/

Comment: @Era I have complex css going on, I do not want to manually combine all the permutations -- ie, I know I can define .greenGradient.iconToo and copy-paste from .greenGradient -- so I want some syntax that will reference the `existing` background-image.

Comment: No luck.. you will have to use different tag for icon.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564239/css-inheriting-layered-background-images (no luck).